# Translating long methods into BigInteger methods

Tags: java, biginteger

I have these two methods that use `long` that I want to use BigInteger instead:

```
public static long findfirstnocommon(long n) {
    long j;
    for(j = 2; j < n; j++)
        if(euclid(n,j) == 1) return j;
    return 0;
}

public static long euclid(long m, long n) { 
    while(m > 0) {
        long t = m;
        m = n % m;
        n = t;
    }
    return n;
}
```

These two methods work really well in the context of my program. However when I translate them to BigIntegers I get this:

```
  public static BigInteger findfirstnocommon(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger j;
    for(j = BigInteger.valueOf(2); j.compareTo(n) == -1; j.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1))){
        if(euclid(n,j).compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(1)) == 0){
            return j;
        }
    }
    return BigInteger.valueOf(0);
}

public static BigInteger euclid(BigInteger m, BigInteger n) { 
    BigInteger zero = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    while(m.compareTo(zero) == 1) {
        BigInteger t = m;
        m = n.mod(m);
        n = t;
    }
    return n;
}
```

When I use them methods and run them in my program it appears to get stuck and not work. I've been trying to see what is wrong and can't figure it out. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1))` does not change `j`.  It returns a *new* `BigInteger` whose value is one more than `j`, but you're discarding it.  Try `j = j.add(BigInteger.ONE)` [this constant is provided for you so you don't have to type `valueOf(1)`].

In fact, `BigInteger` (like `String`) is an *immutable* type, which means there are no methods that change the contents of a `BigInteger` object, only methods that return new `BigInteger` objects.

Comment: Yup, it worked. I knew the issue was the infinite loop there, but I couldn't figure out why. Makes sense that BigInteger objects are an immutable type. Thanks!